Does seemingly unrelated regressions (SUR) with the same dependent variable make sense for a time series?
SUR is a new concept to me and my advisor mentioned it and that I should explore it for my research.
I have a variable (let's call it y) that is my dependant variable. I also have 6 control variables and a variable for sentiment in different countries (let's say, sentiment_country_A and sentiment_country_B).
I have all these variables in a table and their values in a frequency of every three months during 6 years (30 rows).
I want to know how the sentiment from each country affect my dependant variable. So, I thought about creating these two regressions:
y ~ sentiment_country_A + control variables
y ~ sentiment_country_B + control variables
I tried running SUR on them and I received a pretty low R-squared (0.36) and not all variables had the p<0.05. The residuals were also highly correlated (~0.99).
Is this the correct approach for my scenario? Should I use a different method? I don't have a statistics background, so it would be really helpful to get some insight.
